# GIT Multi-tier configuration for environments: [DEV -> QA -> PROD]

Tags: git

I have the following hierarchy like multiple developers push their code and test on their **DEV server**, once that seems to be fine, it should go for QA's Verification on **QA server**, and once QA approves then it should go to **PROD server** which will be available for customers.
e

The code needs to be maintained under GIT.

I would like to know, what is the best practice on how we can configure such structure of CODE flow under SDLC.

Thanks.

Comment: Great question,  but not a good fit for stack overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Git is not a release manager. You can force it to be one, but it won't work well.

Instead, here's the principles of a simple continuous release/delivery workflow.

## There is one long lived branch, `master`.

Even in git, maintaining long lived branches is complicated and best avoided. You have one branch both to develop from and to deploy: master.

## `master` is at all times ready for release.

Nothing goes into master that isn't ready for release. This gives developers a stable platform from which to develop on, QA a stable platform for testing, and you can deploy the latest *complete* features with confidence at any time.

## All development happens in feature branches.

You keep `master` at high quality by doing all development in branches off `master`. This allows each task to be isolated from the others, and developers are free to experiment without breaking the build.

Put another way, your development, integration, testing, and acceptance phases all happen in feature branches. Maintenance also happens as discrete feature branches.

## Feature branches are well defined and short lived.

Keeping with the idea that long lived branches are painful, feature branches should be associated with one ticket, issue, or story. The purpose of the branch should be well defined and it should be clear when it's done. Once it's done, the branch is deleted to ensure it is not reused and to avoid branch clutter.

Your analysis and design phases must result in implementation tasks which can be chopped up into discrete tasks which can be done in a short lived feature branch. This requires some practice to learn how to do.

Use `git merge --no-ff` to ensure the branch is preserved in the topology of the commit history. Use the merge commit message to record any important information about the branch for future archeology such as references to the issue it is solving.

```
A - B ------------- M - N - O [master]
     \             /
      C - D - E - F
```

These are known as "feature bubbles". They make it clear that commits C, D, E, and F were done as a commit and we should look at M for information about the branch. Use `git log --graph --decorate` to get such a view, or any number of Git history visualizers.

## Feature branches are rebased onto master.

To avoid feature branches falling out of date, they are habitually brought up to date with master. No feature is considered complete until it has been brought up to date with master, conflicts resolved, and all tests passing.

To avoid excessive bookkeeping merges, use `git rebase master` to keep history clean. Here's an example of what an out of date feature branch looks like. The F - G "bubble" is a completed feature branch.

```
      F - G
     /     \
A - B ----- H [master]
     \
      C - D - E [feature]
```

And then after rebasing it.

```
git checkout feature
git rebase master

      F - G
     /     \
A - B ----- H [master]
             \
              C1 - D1 - E1 [feature]
```

## Feature branches must pass CI and QA before merging.

This guarantees that master is at all times ready for release. Since feature branches are kept up to date with master, QA on the branch also QA's master after the merge.

## Deploy master to staging and production.

This is what it's all leading to. There are no staging and production branches. At any time you can deploy master to staging. Once you're satisfied it's ready, you can deploy that commit to production. If you like you can also `git tag staging` or `git tag production` the commit which is deployed. This is the workflow used by things such as [Heroku Pipelines](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pipelines).

## What about hot patches?

Make a *temporary* branch off the `production` tag, `git branch hot-patch production`. Commit the hot patches to that branch. Deploy that branch.

Once the emergency is over, and as quickly as possible, redo the hot patches as a normal feature branch and normal deployment process. You can use `git cherry-pick` or `git rebase` to get the hot patch changes on top of `master`. Once the properly done fix is deployed, delete the hot patch branch.

Comment: For me, there is a situation where 5 engineers are working on 5 different features. Out of which 3 completed development at the same time and need to be deployed on staging for QA.
How to handle the situation to release 3 features at the same time on staging?

Comment: @Sarang Each feature is in a feature branch. As each feature branch passes QA they are merged into master. Then deploy master to your staging environment once those three features are merged. If you need *exactly* those three features, they might be one feature.

Comment: Do you suggest to have 3 different QA environments for each of 3 features for a QA team to test?

Comment: @Sarang Yes, ideally you should be able to provision and deploy to QA environments and CI on demand. [Heroku Pipeline](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pipelines)'s Review Apps for example. More generally, see [The Twelve Factor App](https://12factor.net/).